# Stretch the <div> to the full height of the parent <div>

Tags: html, css

There are many div blocks. One parent, the second inside the left (for the menu), the second inside the right (for the text). How it is possible to stretch the right inner block (it is possible with the left one) to the entire height of the parent block. The parent block it has min-height:1100px

Here's the code:

```
<div id="wrapctr">
    <div id="leftmenu"></div>
    <div class="rightcontent">
        //common div
        <div style="padding: 10px; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: space-between; background:white">
            // img div
            <div style="float: left; padding: 10px; text-align: center; width: 257px;"><img src="../img/1625.jpg" width="200"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapctr {
    width:80%;
    min-width: 700px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    background:#FFF;
    margin:0 auto;
    min-height:1100px;
    z-index:2;        
}

#leftmenu { 
    background: #FFF;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    list-style: none;
}
.rightcontent {
    background: #FFF; 
    margin-left: 255px; 
}
```

One page show 12 images are issued in three in a row. If i added `position:relative` and `absolute` with `height:100%` my div with style comes out of rightcontent div

Comment: `width: inherit;` might be the droid you are looking for

Comment: you can add  min-height: 1100px; to right div .rightcontent {
      background: #FFF; 
      margin-left: 255px; 
      min-height: 1100px;
     }

Comment: @gusaindpk thanks, it's works!

Answer (score 0):

You should give wrapctr position relative
and position absolute to your common div 
and then you can give height 100% to the common div